# What event is fired when text is cut or pasted (or ctrl+z'd) in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've been using keyup to detect when content in a textarea changes, but somehow Facebook can detect a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> event in a textbox immediately when the <kbd>X</kbd> is pressed down.  What event would this be?

Comment: Isn't that what `onchange` is for?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought onchange was only when the element lost focus..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most current browsers support `cut`, `copy` and `paste` events. Try the following to prove this to yourself:

```
<textarea oncut="alert('Cut!')" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess they make a bind to the keydown, and set some sort of state variable when the control key is pressed, then when they receive a keyup event, they check the state variable and act accordingly.

Comment: This occurs in one of Facebook's autogrow text boxes.  Basically, the box resizes immediately after CTRL and X is pressed to fit the text, before any keyup event occurs.  I was thinking of implementing a keydown event that also checks if CTRL is pressed, but that wouldn't do me any good because I still don't have the size of the selected text.

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted auto-grow text boxes because your question has nothing to do with that;)

Comment: Well, that was the primary reason, however, I have use for cut and paste other than autogrow text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Hehehe I figured it out on my own!

In the keypress event for the textarea:

```
window.setTimeout((function(self) {
    return function() {
        console.log(self.value);
        }
    })(this), 0);
```

This will give the current value of the textarea as opposed to the value before the key was pressed.  I've only verified this on Firefox 4 so far though.

Now my autogrowing textbox is as nice as Facebook's!